# How to plot with a png as background?

Tags: r, data-visualization, large-data

I made a plot with a 3 million points and saved it as PNG. It took a few hours and I would like to avoid re-drawing all the points.

[image]

How can I generate a new plot that has this PNG as a background?

Comment: Never used it, but package `png` may have what you're after: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/png/png.pdf

Comment: It would be good to add some transparency to your points, so you may see their distribution better. Like in a density plot.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/42611002/15485

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(png)

#Replace the directory and file information with your info
ima <- readPNG("C:\\Documents and Settings\\Bill\\Data\\R\\Data\\Images\\sun.png")

#Set up the plot area
plot(1:2, type='n', main="Plotting Over an Image", xlab="x", ylab="y")

#Get the plot information so the image will fill the plot box, and draw it
lim <- par()
rasterImage(ima, lim$usr[1], lim$usr[3], lim$usr[2], lim$usr[4])
grid()
lines(c(1, 1.2, 1.4, 1.6, 1.8, 2.0), c(1, 1.3, 1.7, 1.6, 1.7, 1.0), type="b", lwd=5, col="white")
```

Below is the plot.

[image]

Answer (score 16):

While @bill_080's answer directly answers your question, is this really what you want? If you want to plot onto this, you'll have to carefully align your coordinate systems. See e.g. [Houston Crime Map](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/Crime-in-Downtown-Houston,-Texas-:-Combining-ggplot2-and-Google-Maps) how this can be done with ggplot2.

For your problem, it seems to me that there may be an easier solution: binning, i.e. ceating 2d histograms.

```
> df <- data.frame (x = rnorm (1e6), y = rnorm (1e6))
> system.time (plot (df))
       User      System verstrichen 
     54.468       0.044      54.658 
> library (hexbin)
> system.time (binned <- hexbin (df, xbins=200))
       User      System verstrichen 
      0.252       0.012       0.266 
> system.time (plot (binned))
       User      System verstrichen 
      0.704       0.040       0.784
```

[image]

hexbin works directly with lattice and ggplot2, but the center coordinates of the bins are in `binned@xcm` and `binned@ycm`, so you could also plot the result in base graphics. With high number of bins, you get a fast version of your original plot:

```
> system.time (plot (binned@xcm, binned@ycm, pch = 20, cex=0.4))
       User      System verstrichen 
      0.780       0.004       0.786
```

[image]

but you can easily have the colours coding the density:

```
> plot (binned@xcm, binned@ycm, pch = 20, cex=0.4, col = as.character (col))

> col <- cut (binned@count, 20)
> levels (col) <- grey.colors (20, start=0.9, end = 0)
> plot (binned@xcm, binned@ycm, pch = 20, cex=0.4, col = as.character (col))
```

[image]