# Text color not honored by image_annotate from the magick package in R of ImageMagick

Tags: r, image, annotations, imagemagick

I have not been able to control the text colour in the image_annotate function of package magick in R.

I have tried the R color name "white" and the hexadecimal colour for white "#FFFFFF" and in both cases the text returned is black.

Other text controls are honored such as font size.

The example below illustrates the issue. When I view the output in the RStudio Plot window the text is black. I get the same results when I write the image to a PNG file

I am using the R version 4.2.2, RStudio Build 676, and Magick version in R 2.7.3

This code demonstates the issue.

```
library(magick)

height <- 100
width <- 80

X <- array(
          runif(height * width * 3, min = 0, max = 255),
          dim = c(height, width, 3)
          )

img <- magick::image_read(X / 255) %>% magick::image_scale("500x400")
img <- magick::image_annotate(img, text = "Example", gravity = "northeast", location = "+50+50", font = "times", size ="20", color = "white")

print(img)

image_write(img, path = "c:/temp/ouput.png")
```

Thank you

Comment: Hi @StéphaneLaurent thanks for letting me know - hopefully a version issue! Can you tell me what version of R you are using? Thanks for testing

Comment: R-4.2.2 on Linux, magick package freshly installed

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I'm using Windows so looks like it is related to that as I get white rendered properly on Linux.
Thanks again