# Plotting a background image in R using rasterimage() going wrong?

Tags: r, background

I wanted to plot a runway behind a few points, so I tried the method suggested in the link : [In R, how to plot with a png as background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12918367/in-r-how-to-plot-with-a-png-as-background) [The correct graph looks like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aS392.jpg) But it seems to work only for one particular image, when I change the image or edit the same image, only the image gets plotted and not the points. [Plot gone wrong.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zf1Qx.jpg)

There must be some silly mistake from my side. Can anyone please point it out as I'm new to R?

```
        plot(x = D, y = G , pch = c(15,16,17,18) , col = c("red", "blue", "green", "orange"), ylim = range(-40,40), xlim = range(0,2500), cex = 1.5)
        img <- readPNG("runway.png")
        lim <- par()
        rasterImage(img, lim$usr[1], lim$usr[3], lim$usr[2], lim$usr[4])}
```

Comment: It would help to submit your code, so that others can see what's going on.

Comment: Thanks Pav, did that :)

Comment: First thing, check your png image. You've got "19L" facing the wrong way -  you should be able to read it from the outside.