# R adding data to an existing graph according to the id number

Tags: r, plot, graph

[image: The layout of the shoping mall]
I want to add the price on the graph according to the id (suppose each room has one unique id with it)

```
id      price
1        $69
2        $74
4        $199
```

is there a way to do this easily with any tools in R?

I think the reply helped me solved how to add the data and put it onto the graph

I need to specify one hard thing regarding this issue
Probably the hardest part is to get the coordinate of the cell in the map, I have hundreds of the graphs need to fill in the price data, can R detect the different cells and tell me the coordinate and fill in the price data?

Comment: Please see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12918367/in-r-how-to-plot-with-a-png-as-background

Comment: See linked post, then create `x,y,id,price` coordinates dataframe, then use `points()`.

Comment: Thanks but I think my question has another issue: I have hundreds of graphs to fill in the price, if I do it manually, it takes months to finish, is there a way to make computer do it? each cell on the graph is separated clearly