# Placing arrow on existing background picture in R

Tags: r, plot

I would like to plot the result of fitted model on existing jpg. The result is between 0 and 1. And I would like the figure (as a pointer) to move nicely along the jpg axis (just about it as shown on the picture below).

[image]

Comment: I think it would be preferable to recreate this scale in R instead of adding a jpg to a plot (which is of course possible).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Overlay data onto Background image in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4993189/overlay-data-onto-background-image-in-r)

Comment: The post is from Feb 2011 and most of the solutions provided are hardly replicable as packages not available. And also it doesn't answer my question so just don't place as duplicate when it is NOT. Or otherwise prove how I can use your reference to solve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that I like the approach of using a ready made scale and adding a pointer to it; but, if you must, here is a way. The tricky part is getting your point plotting to line up with the axis displayed in your jpeg scale:

### Example

First, I made an example jpeg:

```
library(biOps)

#make jpeg of scale
jpeg("scale.jpeg", width=4, height=1, units="in", res=200, quality = 100)
par(mar=c(4,0,0,0), ps=10)
z <- seq(0,1,by=0.1)
breaks <- c(0,0.33,0.67,1)
image(x=z, z=matrix(z, nrow=length(z), ncol=1), xlim=c(0,1), axes=FALSE, xlab="", ylab="", breaks=breaks, col=c("red","yellow", "green"))
axis(1, at=seq(0.1,0.9,0.1))
box()
dev.off()
```

[image]

Then, I load this and place it in the lower panel of a device using `layout`, and added a point above at a given location (e.g. 0.2):

```
#add pointer above figure
pic <- readJpeg("scale.jpeg") # load jpeg

lo <- matrix(2:1, nrow=2, ncol=1) # layout info
WIDTHS <- c(4)
HEIGHTS <- c(0.2,1)

#make new jpeg
jpeg("scale_w_pointer.jpeg", width=4, height=1.2, units="in", res=200, quality = 100)
#quartz() # or x11() to preview
layout(lo, widths=WIDTHS, heights=HEIGHTS, respect=TRUE)
layout.show(2)

#plot 1
par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))
plot(pic)

#plot 2
par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))
plot(1, xlim=c(0,1), ylim=c(0,1), t="n", xaxs="i", yaxs="i", xlab="", ylab="", axes=FALSE)
points(0.2, 0.30, pch=25, bg=1, col=1)

dev.off()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit rough but should get you started. With scan, tcltk or shiny you could make this interactive/responsive and/or write to file as needed.

```
col <- c("green", "yellow", "red")
x <- matrix(col, nrow = 1L) 

plot(0, xlim = c(0, 1), ylim = c(0, 0.5), asp = 1, 
  xlab = "", ylab = "", axes = FALSE, type = "n")
axis(1, at = seq(0, 1, length = 6), line = -6, lwd = 0, lwd.tick = 1)

rasterImage(x, 0, 0, 1, 0.05, interpolate = FALSE)

p   <- cbind(c(0, 0.015, -0.015, 0) + runif(1), c(0.05, 0.065, 0.065, 0.05))
polygon(p, col = "black")
```

Comment: Thanks!I was going along this lines too.