# How can I add the color scale on the topright of an exist png image with R code?

Tags: r, image, colors

How can I add the color scale on the topright of an exist png image with R code? 
The color scale is made by "KEGGprofile" R package. The code is:

```
col = col_by_value(temp, col=colorRampPalette(c('yellow','white','blue'))(1024), range=c(min(temp),max(temp))).
```

The temp data is:

```
Proteome    Phosphoproteome
10365   0.1936665   0.8226708
3320    -0.6043064  0.3554265
596 -1.8526172  -0.4719894
6300    1.2375722   1.3151508
659 0.1260142   -0.6054770
858 -1.4846932  1.6420495
```

The color scale look like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Er4ao.png)
[image]

The exist png image is as follows:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXR09.png)
[image]

How to zoom out and Rotate the color scale figure and paste it into the png imge (Just as follows). The number is the color scale can also be clear.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDq9J.png)
[image]

Comment: You could have a look at the `png` package, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4993189/overlay-data-onto-background-image should help you to get started

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the function `readPNG` to read the exist figure, use `rasterImage` to plot the figure and use `image.plot` to add the color scale. while the parameter `horizontal` in `image.plot` function can Rotate the legend and `smallplot` can size the legend. By the way, you can adjust the size of legend scale by `axis.args` parameter.

```
library(png)
library(graphics)
library(grDevices)
library(fields)

img=readPNG("hsa00310_profile_bg.png")
width=ncol(img)
height=nrow(img)
png(file="hsa00310_profile_bg.png",width=width,height=height)
par(yaxs="i")
par(xaxs="i")
par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))
plot(c(0,width), c(0,height), type='n', xlab="", ylab="")
rasterImage(img, 0, 0, width, height,interpolate=F)
image.plot(legend.only=T, zlim=c(-2,2), col=colorRampPalette(c('yellow', 'white', 'red'))(1024), horizontal 
=TRUE, legend.shrink=0.1, smallplot = c(.9,.99, .92,.95), axis.args = list(cex.axis = 2))
dev.off()
```

[image]